# MFC toolbox control

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm totally new to MFC.  In fact I haven't even written anything in it yet.

I'm looking for a control similar to the one found here: http://sourceforge.net/dbimage.php?id=48455

"Toolbox", left hand side.

The CMFCOutlookBar is somewhat close but the images are quite large and the text appears beneath the icon, not beside it.  Looking at the button adding functions I don't see any way to change that.

So, is there a prebuilt component in the MFC lib that does what I want?

VS2010 - featurepack stuff is included.

Comment: If its not in the BCGSoft stuff (VS2010 feature pack) then your best bet would be http://www.codejock.com/, but it is commercial software. You can also try digging around on CodeProject and CodeGuru.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BCGSoft has this component: 
http://www.bcgsoft.com/featuretour/tour168.htm